# Scraping images and changin its name with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a project which scrapes images from Tumblr using Python.
I want to download the images found on the links I get scraping.

This is the entire code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import shutil
search_term = "landscape/recent"
posts_scrape = requests.get(f"https://www.tumblr.com/search/{search_term}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(posts_scrape.text, "html.parser")

articles = soup.find_all("article", class_="FtjPK")

data = {}
for article in articles:
    try:
        source = article.find("div", class_="vGkyT").text
        for imgvar in article.find_all("img", alt="Image"):
            data.setdefault(source, []).extend(
                [
                    i.replace("500w", "").strip()
                    for i in imgvar["srcset"].split(",")
                    if "500w" in i
                ]
            )
    except AttributeError:
        continue


for source, image_urls in data.items():
    for url in image_urls:
        if posts_scrape.status_code == 200:
            url.raw.decode_content = True
            with open(source,'wb') as f:
                shutil.copyfileobj(url.raw, f)
            print('Image sucessfully Downloaded: ',source)
        else:
            print('Image Couldn\'t be retrieved')
```

Following an answer on this post i changed the code and used `request` and `shutil`:

```
for source, image_urls in data.items():
    for url in image_urls:
        if posts_scrape.status_code == 200:
            url.raw.decode_content = True
            with open(source,'wb') as f:
                shutil.copyfileobj(url.raw, f)
            print('Image sucessfully Downloaded: ',source)
        else:
            print('Image Couldn\'t be retrieved')
```

And now I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/folder/Information.py", line 28, in <module>
    url.raw.decode_content = True
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'raw'
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `requests` to fetch the images?  Why use an external tool when you have the same thing built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to make `request` again with the image URL. Then you can get the response in raw form and save the image

replace the code with this below -

```
for source, image_urls in data.items():
    for url in image_urls:
        # make request with image url 
        img_scrape = requests.get(url, stream=True)

        if img_scrape.status_code == 200:
            with open(source,'wb') as f:
                img_scrape.raw.decode_content = True
                
                # save the image raw format
                shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
            print('Image sucessfully Downloaded: ',source)
        else:
            print('Image Couldn\'t be retrieved')
```

Output -

```
Image sucessfully Downloaded:  pics-bae
Image sucessfully Downloaded:  pics-bae
Image sucessfully Downloaded:  laravel
Image sucessfully Downloaded:  huariqueje
Image sucessfully Downloaded:  sweetd3lights
Image sucessfully Downloaded:  shesinthegrove
Image sucessfully Downloaded:  careful-disorder
Image sucessfully Downloaded:  beifongkendo
Image sucessfully Downloaded:  traveltoslovenia
Image sucessfully Downloaded:  traveltoslovenia
Image sucessfully Downloaded:  traveltoslovenia
Image sucessfully Downloaded:  bradsbackpack
Image sucessfully Downloaded:  pensamentsisomnis
Image sucessfully Downloaded:  frankfurtphoto
........

..........
```